# How to validate start date should be greater than current date in yii

Tags: validation, yii

I had a form in which a start date field is there. I need to check whether the start date entered is greater than Current date using yii validation rule.

Can any one help me in doing this?

Comment: How are you storing the date? Can you show the code for the model that has this date field?

Comment: $criteria->compare('startDate',$this->startDate,true);

Comment: @ Jon can we write a rule in function rules to check this ?

Comment: Of course, but you still haven't shown the model.

Answer (score 2):

This might work (needs to be added to the model rules)

```
array('startDate', 'compare', 'compareValue' => date("Y-m-d"), 'operator' => '>'),
```

Comment: should work except that the operator should be `>`, as op has asked for greater. @am123 do note that the `compareValue` should be specified in your expected format for `startDate`.

Comment: spoke too fast in my last comment, `compare` compares as strings, so it'll not work for all date formats, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270902/yii-rule-age-18#comment18088738_13270902)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $date_today          = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' -1 day')); 
                           // -1, -2 depend on how back you want to go!!
  $date_today          = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date_today));
  
   return [   
        [
          'alert_start_date', 'compare', 'compareValue' => $date_today, 
                                                 'operator' => '>',   
          'message' => $attribute.'Alert Start Date Cannot be a date in the past'
        ], 
    ];
```